# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost3000

Tags: angular, ubuntu, firefox, cors, nestjs

proxy.conf.json from angular and also configured that file in angular.json in "serve":

```
{
    "/front-v1": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

My service file:

```
async getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.getDataUrl,
      {headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': this.getDataUrl,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': ''
      }, responseType: 'json'} ).pipe((result) => {
      return result;
    });
  }
```

main.ts from nestjs

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  // app.enableCors();
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });
  app.enableCors({
    allowedHeaders:"*",
    origin: "*",
});
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

This is my ERROR:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost3000/india. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

**SOLUTION**

The issue was in my proxy at client-side. Make proxy.config correctly.

Comment: You really want to remove all those cors headers from your client code. It doesn’t work and can actually cause Cors issues..

Answer (score -1):

You can specify `cors: true` in the app initialization. `cors: true` will set the default cors configuration which is to allow all origin. or you can specify your own configuration.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: true,
});
```

Comment: i tried but didn't work..

Comment: i am running on ubuntu.. is there any problem with ubuntu,, Thanks.

Comment: your os shouldn't be a problem. have you tried remove other codes and keep only `const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });`